# Is there a way to set the ls command to always stack results in one column?

Tags: command-line, bash

Not a fan of touchpads, so I tend to do all of my regular file navigation in the terminal. I've done `cd path/to/whatever <enter> ls` so many times that it's just muscle memory now and feels more natural than using a GUI to navigate files. However, sometimes when there's a lot of files stacked in several columns, it can be less than intuitive to find what I'm looking for. I know I can just to `ls -l` to list them like that (plus some extra info), but I don't what to have to type that every time. But even if there was a way to just permanently tag the `-l` flag onto every `ls` command, that would work too. Anyone know how I can accomplish this? Also, it would be nice if once this were accomplished there was a way to tag something onto an `ls` command in case every once in a while I did need to list them the normal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy. Add a line

```
alias ls='ls -l'
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file and restart the terminal.

You will be able to run `ls` a normal way without `-l` this way

```
\ls
```

Comment: @Nathan there's also `ls -1` which stacks in one column without the extra detail.